# Regex to find anchor tags which are without http or https in the href attribute

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have this sample text on which i want to run the regex to pull the anchor tags whose href doesn't contain http|https in the address part.

I was trying with this regex, and it is not complete yet. I am not able to pluck the anchor when they do not start with http or https.

Link to gskinner site - http://regexr.com?34ev0

```
<a.*?href=[""|'](http|https:\/\/)(?<link>[^""|']*)[""|'].*?>
```

Here is the sample string:-

```
<br /><span style="font-size: 16px;"><strong><a target="_blank" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Good Link (Yahoo)</a><br /><br /><a target="_blank" href="www.bbc.com">Bad Link (BBC)</a><br /><br /><a href="" id="anchorSocialMedia" onclick="ShowModalPopup('anchorSocialMedia','/Events/Popup/SocialMediaShareModal.aspx','650px','500px');">Share This Event</a><br />Badge Perf Testing<br /><br /></strong></span>
```

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JavaScript regex methods (there are equivalents in pretty much all languages):

```
<your string>.match(/<a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*"[^"]*"[^>]*>/g)
.join('')
.match(/href\s*=\s*"(?!https?:\/\/)[^"]*"/g);
```

OR

```
<your string>.match(/<a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*"(?!https?:\/\/)[^"]*"[^>]*>/g)
.map(function(x){return x.replace(/.*(href\s*=\s*"[^"]*").*/,'$1');})
```

You choose!

Comment: The greedy `[^<]+` is problematic, I think.

Comment: how come? was the only reliable I could think of at the time to keep the capture within the <a> itself..

Comment: Consider: `<a img="abc.gif"> href="ftp://example.com" </a>`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think changing [^<] to [^>] would fix this right?

Comment: It certainly is an improvement. I could be a bastard and devise: `<alarm href="ftp://example.com">`, I suppose, but I gave you a +1 anyway

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, that would be bastardly... I will fix that too... ! cheers.

Comment: How about this one.. <a.*?href="([^http]|[^https]).*?"[^<]

Comment: it won't work.. will match all sorts of strings that you don't seem to want. I _may_ be able to prettify the above a little bit though...

Comment: Good enough, I think.  Part of the art of the regex is knowing when you've reached a 'good enough' solution. There's a solid argument that parsing HTML with regexes is a bad idea, but you can often get by as long as you aren't having to deal with absolutely anything that could be thrown at the regex.

Comment: @Karan: the non-greedy `.*?` trips on my 'consider' example.

Comment: Is there something wrong Karan?? - if it fails somehow, please say how - otherwise please tick/thumb it up so others will know what's up. cheers :)